# python re.match() returns true when part of the string matches

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

This might be trivial for those in this forum, but I ended up debugging this for the entire day. I have a python script running, but the issue boils down to this:

```
import re
spice="IN_N1"
rtl="IN_N13"
re.match(spice,rtl)
```

This returns a match object. Python seems to match the string IN_N1 anywhere in the second string and returns a match. I want it to compare the entire string and return a no match for this case. In other words, I want the above to be a match only if spice="IN_N13". It would be great if someone can suggest a solution.
Thanks!

Comment: `spice==rtl`? No need to use regular expressions for this.

Answer (score 2):

Your Python regexp is interpreted as `IN_N1.*`

Change your pattern to `IN_N1$` and it should work.

However consider Aleksanders comment ;)

//Edit: fixed regexp to consider comment

Comment: Note they're using match, not search, so `^` is implied.

Comment: I made it spice='^IN_N1$' and rtl= '^IN_N1$'. In this case it says no match. However, assuming that ^ is implied, I just modified spice="IN_N1$" and rtl="IN_N1". This works- and returns a match. Making rtl="IN_N13" says no match. So, adding a $ at the end works. Of course the equality operator also works. Thanks!

Comment: Sure the first doesn't work ;) ^ in regexp is for the line beginning and $ for the line end.
If you put it in the string you're searching in, then those characters are normal characters (not regexp expressions) and thus the regexp won't match.